# How can I edit programmatically created buttons in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I have this code which generates a GUI programmatically

```
 TableLayout table;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        table = new TableLayout(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        table.setLayoutParams(lp);
        table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
        TableRow.LayoutParams cellLp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
        int count = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; ++r) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
                count++;
                final Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setText("");
                btn.setId(count);

                btn.setOnClickListener(this);

                row.addView(btn, cellLp);
            }
            table.addView(row, rowLp);
        }
        TableRow erow = new TableRow(this);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Reset");
        btn.setId(10);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        erow.addView(btn, cellLp);
        table.addView(erow, rowLp);
        setContentView(table);
        }
```

In the listener, I can change the text of the button I click this way

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button)v;
    btn.setText("text");
    }
```

But, how, can I interact with other buttons? I have tried with something like `btn = (Button)findViewById(7);` but it doesn't work.
I also tried with an array of buttons but still doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: Are you able to see the code when you go to the layout file? If yes, can you see the ids of the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById()` is mainly for views created by inflating XML layout files.

Though you can call `setId()` for views, in this case you should keep simply references to the programmatically created views, i.e.

```
private Button button1;
```

and then just use those fields.

Comment: I solved using an array of field buttons. In the first attempt I did (because yes, I did one before asking this question), not only it didn't work but used to make app crash. After some correction I found that there was a mistake and now it works. Thanks! I just wanted to be sure it was a good way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Tag` instead `id` for your buttons:

```
for (...) {
    count++;
    final Button btn = new Button(this);
    ...
    btn.setTag(count);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
}
```

And in listener call `(Integer)v.getTag()`